# Snowflake SQL listing session counts per hour (group by day and hour)

Tags: sql, database, data-mining, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to count unique session tokens/hour from a Snowflake table of user transactions.
Although I perform a count-distinct and group by Date and hour I just get one result record for each day.

My query is:

```
select to_date(EVENT_TIMESTAMP) as SessDate,
   date_part(hour, current_timestamp()) as SessHour,
   count(distinct event_data:"u-token") as userTokenCount
from
  APPTRANSACTIONTABLE
where
  event_timestamp BETWEEN '2020-03-12T00:00:00.00' AND '2020-03-14T23:59:59.59'
group by SessHour, SessDate
order by SessHour, SessDate
```

But my result displays only one record per day whereas I want to display results by date and by hour.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `datepart()` has the wrong timestamp (`current_timestamp` rather than `EVENT_TIMESTAMP`):

```
select to_date(EVENT_TIMESTAMP) as SessDate,
       date_part(hour, EVENT_TIMESTAMP) as SessHour,
       count(distinct event_data:"u-token") as userTokenCount
from APPTRANSACTIONTABLE
where event_timestamp BETWEEN '2020-03-12T00:00:00.00' AND '2020-03-14T23:59:59.59'
group by SessHour, SessDate
order by SessHour, SessDate;
```

I would also suggest writing the `WHERE` clause more simply as:

```
where event_timestamp >= '2020-03-12' AND
      event_timestamp < '2020-03-15'
```

There is no reason to filter out events that occur one second before midnight.  You can also use `date_trunc()` for further simplification:

```
select date_trunc('hour', EVENT_TIMESTAMP) as session_day_hour,
       count(distinct event_data:"u-token") as userTokenCount
from APPTRANSACTIONTABLE
where event_timestamp >= '2020-03-12' AND
      event_timestamp < '2020-03-15'
group by session_day_hour
order by session_day_hour;
```